# “Not able to post data on published Web API” – 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angular, cors, angular9, http-status-code-405

I am using angular and when i post data to web api from local machine it will work but when same web api i publish on server i am not able to post data. I am getting 405 (Method Not Allowed).
I Create "proxy.conf.js" file in src folder

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://**********.net",
  "secure": false,
   "changeOrigin": true,
  "logLevel": "debug"

 }

}
```

and i add it to angular.json

```
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "********:build",
        "proxyConfig":  "proxy.config.json"

      },
```

but not change i still getting 405 error when i try to post data to the server

Answer (score -1):

Your method should Be POST, check your method

Comment: what is the target url example?, i believe url you are trying to access is wrong

Comment: @Andrei i try it the url in postman  and it work fine i think the problem is in the proxy config but i can't find it

Comment: http://**********.net this one but i hide it because it for privacy

Comment: please, provide the path. domain is not useful but path matters. what is the url after ".net"?

Comment: it seems my guess wasn't true

Comment: if it wasn't true it will show 404 @Andrei

Comment: maybe but i don't think so in my case

Comment: if you believe that API works fine, then check metod in request that you send from you FE

Comment: in localhost it work fine but when i publish it on server it shows 405

Comment: wow, how do you serve your application on the server? usually angular proxy is used only for development